# htaccess rewrite problem

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new on stackoverflow.com and also in .htaccess.

I just ask one thing:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=156$
RewriteRule ^test1.php?$ /htaccess_test/test.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=154$
RewriteRule ^test1.php?$ /htaccess_test/test2.php
```

I just want to merge these two rewrite rules because i have lots of these kinds of rules. So i just want to wrap up these things instead of writing two more lines each and every time for new event_id.

Can you please tell me how can i write this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you want to redirect test1.php to test.php or test2.php due to different event_id.
I don't think you can merge these two rules because the destination is not the same due to different conditions. But you can merge the different event_id to the same condition, like you want event_id 156 157 158 to redirect to test.php, want 152 153 154 to redirect to test2.php, you can write this way:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=156$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=157$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=158$
RewriteRule ^test1.php?$ /htaccess_test/test.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=152$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=153$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=154$
RewriteRule ^test1.php?$ /htaccess_test/test2.php
```

Hope this help you more or less.

Comment: Agreed, two destinations means two blocks of rewrite conditions/rules. But couldn't you knock it down further to something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=(156|157|158)$`? If the list gets too long, then your way probably reads more easily. But if each block only has a few choices, then this way might be more compact but still readable.

Comment: @David Weinraub, yeah, your option is very good. I've thought this type of code RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=(156|157|158)$, but just as you said, as he is a beginner, the way I wrote is more readable, I think. :)

Comment: thanx Michael. Actually i just want to know that can we merge those two rules or not. thanx to David also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this combined code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=(156|154)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test1\.php/?$ /htaccess_test/test.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanx anubhava. Actually dear, I just combinded the above two rules. Above there are two urls with named test.php and test2.php. I just want to combine those two urls.